# javascript sum up value in array and not all values in array

Tags: javascript

Right now I am working on this function to litterlay sum up.
The array looks for example like this: `var array = ['5','2','8'];`
I want to litterly say `array[0] +1` or something like this. 
I look at reduce but that sums up all the values with each other, that is not what it is supposed to do. What should come out is when `sum` is 1, and you want the first value in the array. In this case is the first one is 5 : `5 + 1 = 6`. Then 6 should come out of it and replace the place of 5 in the array.

This is an example of what I got right now.

```js
var array = ['6','2','5'];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  array = array[i];
  var sum = 1;
  array = sum + array[0];
  console.log(array); 
}
```

Comment: please add a wanted outcome. you overwrite `array` and it becomes not clear, what you like to achieve.

Comment: Do you want to add 1 to each number in the array?

Comment: So what is the outcome supposed to be?

Comment: no I want to add 1 to only one value in the array and not all of them

Comment: array[index]++ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single value, you could take the value (taking an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) for making a number) and increment it (make a string again), then assign it to the same index.

```js
var array = ['6', '2', '5'];

array[0] = (+array[0] + 1).toString();

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to litterly say array[0] +1 or something like this.

Looks like you want to increment all the values by **1**.

Try this appoach

```js
var array = ['6','2','5'];
array = array.map( a => String( Number(a) + 1 ) );
console.log(array);
```

If you want to keep them `Number` instead of `String`, then remove the wrapping with `String` constructor

```js
var array = ['6','2','5'];
array = array.map( a => Number(a) + 1 );
console.log(array);
```

**Edit - Based on comment and question update**

> no I want to add 1 to only one value in the array and not all of them
>
> What should come out is when sum is 1, and you want the first value in
>   the array.

No need for iteration then

```js
var array = ['6','2','5'];
var sum = 1;
array[ sum - 1 ] = String( Number( array[ sum - 1 ] ) + 1 );
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) to convert the first element `array[0]` to a number and than add 1 and finally add `''` to make it a string again:

```js
var array = ['6','2','5'];
array[0] = +array[0] + 1 + '';

console.log(array);
```

Comment: OP wants `no I want to add 1 to only one value in the array and not all of them`

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.addScalar=function(value){
   var cloneArray=[];
   this.forEach(function(entry){
     //it is weird that your array is ['1', '2'] instead of [1,2]
     //but this "if" handles it
     if ( typeof(entry)==='string') {
        cloneArray.push(parseInt(entry)+value);
     } else {
        cloneArray.push(entry+value);
     }
   });
   return cloneArray;
}

['1',2,3].addScalar(1) //[2, 3, 4]
```